# Memory semantics of a computed array property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, properties

This is for an app that allows users to tag things. Tags are just strings.

An array of `TagHolder` objects holds a list of all tags in use in the app, with a boolean telling if the tag is selected, but this is an implementation detail.

The external interface calls for two methods, `selectedTags`, and `setSelectedTags:` which return and accept an arrays of strings.

I would like these two methods to work as accessors for a declared property `selectedTags`.

Now, my question is:

What would be the correct memory management semantics to declare for that property?

The code pattern that I have in mind is this (code not tested, so please bear with typos):

```
@interface TagInfo : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tag;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL selected;
@end


@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (memorytype, nonatomic) NSArray *selectedTags;
@end

@implementation TagHolder

- (NSArray *)selectedTags
{
    // tagInfoArray is an array of all TagInfo objects
    NSPredicate *selPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"selected == YES"];
    NSArray *selectedTagInfoObjects = [[self tagInfoArray] filteredArrayUsingPredicate: selPred];

    NSArray *selectedTags = [selectedTagInfoObjects valueForKey: @"tag"];
    return selectedTags;
}

- (void)setSelectedTags: (NSArray *)selectedTags
{
    for (TagInfo *tagInfo in [self tagInfoArray]) {
        tagInfo.selected = [selectedTags containsObject: tagInfo.tag];
    }
}

@end
```

What should `memorytype` be? Obviously not strong or weak, but I think it could be any one of `assign`, `copy` or even `unsafe_unretained`, but which one is the most correct for a computed property with an object value?

I normally use ARC, but I guess the question is the same in an environment with manual retain count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memorytype` is significant only when you `@synthesize` your property accessors. Since you are providing your own implementation for both the getter and the setter, the things you put in parentheses after `@property` are ignored; I usually put `readonly` or `readwrite` there, just to remind myself of what kind of access is available on these properties.

Your code is correct, it will work without creating memory issues with or without ARC.