# Creating dictionary with custom class object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have Custom class. I want to add to this class property with type NSDictionary that will return properties of this class by given tag. But I can not do it. Is it possible or not? I have error:

```
  [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

CODE:

```
@interface Car : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *topic;  
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *car;  
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *variables;
@end
```

```
@implementation Car
- (NSDictionary *)variables
{
return @{
         @"781" : _topic, 
         @"782" : _car,  
}};
@end
```

Comment: You might want to consider making `variables` a readonly property, or better yet, just a plain old method.

Comment: @jlehr While I agree, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10758831/2792531y) seems to suggest it may not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because you are attempting to insert `nil` (probably an uninitialized/unallocated object) into an Objective-C collection which cannot be done.  If you need to represent `nil` in an Objective-C collection, you need to use instead `[NSNull null]`.

---

Based on the code you've added, the problem is that you've not initialized your variables.

There's a problem elsewhere, and you need to initialize these at some point to something (perhaps in `init`?), but to be certain that the error never occurs again, you can do this:

```
- (NSDictionary *)variables {
    return @{
        @"781" : _topic ?: [NSNull null], 
        @"782" : _car ?: [NSNull null],  
    }
};
```

Comment: nhgrif, thanks, how, can I return value of variable _topic of instance of this class?

Comment: This **will** return the value of the variable `_topic` with `nil` (a potential value) represented as an `NSNull` object.  If you're getting the `NSNull` object back then you've not initialized `_topic` and it has no value...